Command failed with exit code 127: npm start
So I just setup a website and when I try to deploy it in netlify with the build command npm start, it is showing me this error.
Command failed with exit code 127: npm start
$ npm start
2:11:37 PM: > nasa_project@1.0.0 start
2:11:37 PM: > nodemon app.js
2:11:37 PM: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2:11:37 PM: ​
2:11:37 PM: "build.command" failed
2:11:37 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:11:37 PM: ​
2:11:37 PM:   Error message
2:11:37 PM:   Command failed with exit code 127: npm start (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-127)
2:11:37 PM: ​
2:11:37 PM:   Error location
2:11:37 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:11:37 PM:   npm start
2:11:37 PM: ​
2:11:37 PM:   Resolved config
2:11:37 PM:   build:
2:11:37 PM:     command: npm start
2:11:37 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
2:11:37 PM:     environment:
2:11:37 PM:       - NASA_API_KEY
2:11:37 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo
2:11:37 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
2:11:37 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:11:37 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
this is my app.js---
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let inputDate = "";

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');

  const date = new Date();
  const currentDate = date.toJSON().slice(0, 10);

  const apikey = process.env.NASA_API_KEY;
  // apiKey=keyFile.config();
  url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=' + apikey + '&date=' + inputDate;

  https.get(url, function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (data) {
      const nasaData = JSON.parse(data);
      const imageUrl = nasaData.hdurl;
      const title = nasaData.title;
      const abouImage = nasaData.explanation;
      res.render("IOD", {
        picTitle: title,
        image: imageUrl,
        about: abouImage,
        currentDate: currentDate,
      });
      // console.log("statusCode- " + response.statusCode);
    });


  });


});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  inputDate = req.body.date;
  res.redirect('/');
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  // console.log('Sever started at port no 3000');
});


this is my package.json---
{
  "name": "nasa_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "`",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/6370409016/Nasa-project.git"
  },
  "author": "Badal Kumar Behera",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/6370409016/Nasa-project/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/6370409016/Nasa-project#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}


